# FOSUserBundle Symfony 2.6.7 - PHP Fatal Error: cannot redeclare class

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, fosuserbundle

unfortunately the porject I'm working on is not public because it is an Intranet. So I will do my very best to describe my problem and make it easy to answer.

I have a clean Symfony 2.6 installation. I have installed FOSUserBundle (current Version) by using composer. I followed the instructions in the documentation on git hub and one step before I finished my work successful, I got this message:

(Console)

```
C:\Development\Webserver\htdocs\Intranet>php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Intranet\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User in C:\Development\Webserver\htdocs\Intranet\src\Intranet\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User.p
hp on line 17

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Intranet\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User in C:\Development\Webserver\htdocs\Intranet\src\Intranet\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User.php on
 line 17
[2015-05-22 15:29:22] php.EMERGENCY: Fatal Compile Error: Cannot redeclare class Intranet\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User {"type":64,"file":"C:\\Development\\Webserver\\h
tdocs\\Intranet\\src\\Intranet\\Bundle\\UserBundle\\Entity\\User.php","line":17,"level":-1,"stack":[]}
```

This is my User.php

```
// src/Intranet/Bundle/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace Intranet\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * User
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

The namespace is correctly written and I cannot find any other mistakes, issues or anything. Until now I'm quite desperate and I hope that someone could help me.

Thanks ahead for reading and trying to help.
Kind regards - Peter

Comment: You probably have another class with same name (I don't mean a file with same nane but a Class). This error doesn't seem to be related to FOSUserBundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably already have a User class declared somewhere, you could try to perform a search for "class User" on your project